# XPath has invalid token

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

In case of special character (&) I am replacing & with (&amp); in my xpath sgtring but when I am compiling this path it gives me invalid token. code is given below

```
        string xpath = "/ Root[1] / vehicleSpecifications[1] / Specifications[1] / General[1] / Average_&amp;Distance[1]";

        try
        {
            XPathExpression.Compile(xpath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: show your xml and expected output.

Comment: XPath is not itself XML; `&` does not need escaping. And XML does not allow `&` in entity names (escaped or unescaped), so this query can't be correct in any case -- neither `Average_&Distance` nor `Average_&amp;Distance` are valid as element names.